# 1.9.2 completely inconsistent order email problem

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, order-email

We have a VPS running litespeed with four website frontends on CE 1.9.2.

It is experiencing really inconsistent new order email problems. Sometimes the email goes. Sometimes it doesn't - that's close to 50/50, we then have outliers where the order email sends two or three times.

Most times when the email doesn't send automatically, I can manually queue another email and it will send on schedule, although sometimes I have to do that twice to get a success.

Looking at the exception log on the failures we are getting a fairly generic looking exception:

```
ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/magento/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php:137

Stack trace:
#0 /home/magento/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
#1 /home/magento/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#2 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Queue.php(239): Zend_Mail->send()
#3 [internal function]: Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
#4 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#5 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#6 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#7 /home/magento/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#8 /home/magento/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
#9 /home/magento/public_html/cron.php(77): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
#10 {main}
```

Please help, we have run out of ideas.

Comment: Just a thought, have you checked the cron_schedule to ensure that there isn't another task pushing the email queue to run too late? You would see "Too late for the schedule" if this was the case.

Comment: Do you have  check other emails like account register, forgot passoword? If it will not work then  the email is not configure at ur server/magento instance

Comment: All other emails are going as intended, it is only on cronjobs that it is failing and that is at this stage unpredictable. I am going to start logging times of failure etc. Have asked the SA to check contents of cron_schedule as well, hopefully that shows the answer. There are a few jobs running on the 5 minute schedule, and we have it configured as: */5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=default
*/5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=always

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions guys. It looks like it is now working. In brief, I pushed the cron schedule to run on offset minutes.
We had cron configured as
*/5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=default
*/5 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=always
as suggested in: [Which cron script is best to run? cron.php or cron.sh](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63707/which-cron-script-is-best-to-run-cron-php-or-cron-sh)
One way or another, with the other jobs running at those times on our VPS or from those two commands interrupting each other, this must've been the cause of our problem. I changed the schedule for job one to 1-59/5 and job two to 2-59/5 and since then, every order email has delivered successfully (and only once which is a bonus).