# Magento cron job not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

I have a magento site hosted on a hostgator shared plan. It only allows me to run cron jobs which are more than 15 mins. I have used the following format to run the cron job.

```
*/15    *   *   *   *   php /home/username/public_html/path/cron.php
```

Still my 'cron_schedule' table is empty. I have also set the cron.php file permission to 755. (Magento ver. 1.9.2.1)

====Update=====

Contacted hostgator, They ran the script manually and still the 'cron_schedule' table is empty.

Comment: contact hostgator, mostly they will fix for you.....

Comment: Contacted host gator. They ran the cron.php script manually and still the 'cron_schedule' table is empty.

Comment: It would be better to change the cronjob to cron.sh instead of cron.php and make sure cron.php is not available from public, as anyone else could trigger your cronjobs then. See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/63717/231

Comment: */15 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=default
*/15 *   * * *   www-data /bin/sh /path/to/magento/cron.sh cron.php -m=always
Added these two cron jobs as well. But still it was also no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Installed a plugin called AOE Scheduler from this url https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

And then i went to `schedule -> Job Configuration and clicked Generate Schedule button.` Then it gave me an exception. The exception was a about a 3rd party plugin called `cron doctor`. I uninstalled the plugin and my cron jobs started working fine.